# \Crefformat does not respect subsection formatting

Tags: cleveref

I am having some trouble getting \Crefformat to honor the formatting for subsections. My (non)working example is as follows.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{url}

\usepackage[colorlinks,                                                                                                
             linkcolor=black!75!red,                                                                                   
             citecolor=blue,                                                                                           
             pdftitle={},                                                                                              
             pdfproducer={pdfLaTeX},                                                                                   
             pdfpagemode=None,                                                                                         
             bookmarksopen=true                                                                                        
             bookmarksnumbered=true]{hyperref}

\usepackage[amsmath,thmmarks,hyperref]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\crefname{section}{Section}{Sections}
\crefformat{section}{#2Section~#1#3}
\Crefformat{section}{#2Section~#1#3}

\crefname{subsection}{Subsection}{Subsections}
\crefformat{subsection}{#2Boo#1#3}
\Crefformat{subsection}{#2Boo#1#3}

\begin{document}

\section{One}\label{se}

\subsection{one.one}\label{subse}

\Cref{se}

\Cref{subse}

\end{document}
```

The *section* `Cref` command behaves as expected: it displays a clickable `Section 1`. The second call to `Cref`, though, displays `Subsection 1.1` with `Subsection` *un*clickable (so the hyperlink only spans the `1.1`).

This is what I would expect if my `\Crefformat{subsection}` simply indicated `#2#1#3`. What puzzles me is that the `Boo` in the `\Crefformat{subsection}` command is completely ignored.

Comment: Why not use the `nameinlink` option as in `\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}
\crefname{section}{Section}{Sections}
\crefname{subsection}{Subsection}{Subsections}`?

Comment: Unrelated, but I think hyperref should be uld be loaded after ntheorem, the hyperref option just prepares ntheorem for hyperref

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cleveref` resets lots of stuff exploiting `\AtBeginDocument` and doing so it overwrites your setting; better delay your own definition:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{url}

\usepackage[colorlinks,
             linkcolor=black!75!red,
             citecolor=blue,
             pdftitle={},
             pdfproducer={pdfLaTeX},
             pdfpagemode=None,
             bookmarksopen=true
             bookmarksnumbered=true]{hyperref}

\usepackage[amsmath,thmmarks,hyperref]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\crefname{section}{Section}{Sections}
\crefformat{section}{#2Section~#1#3}
\Crefformat{section}{#2Section~#1#3}

\crefname{subsection}{Subsection}{Subsections}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \crefformat{subsection}{#2Boo#1#3}%
  \Crefformat{subsection}{#2Boo#1#3}%
}

\begin{document}

\section{One}\label{se}

\subsection{one.one}\label{subse}

\Cref{se}

\Cref{subse}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This worked beautifully, so I've accepted the answer. Thank you!